# How to emulate touch based text selection on a web page

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari

I need to do some web development on my PC .One of my requirement develop a functionality based on touch based text selection on a mobile device (where copy/paste menu) pop up .
How can i mimic this on desktop ?

Comment: Wasn't tap the counterpart of click? Wasn't flick the counterpart of drag?

Comment: This isn't a good question for stack overflow, but as sawa said, you're just looking for click. Personally, I'd be more explicit and go with mousedown -> set a timer to fire after x seconds (however long it is to show the mobile-like context menu) and then display it. Clear the flag on mouseup so it doesn't show if you release too quickly.

Comment: @sawa yes but how can i mimic those behaviour on desktop emulators like chrome inbuilt emulator for touch devices ?